# Java problem - java, Jar file Statmetrics is not running

Tags: java, jar

Download link: `https://upload.cat/f694139f88c663b1`

I am trying to run Java file either as jar or as classes in Ubuntu. I failed in both options. The following exception is its output.

> java org.statmetrics.Statmetric

or

> java -cp /home/elias/statmetrics/statmetrics.jar:.
>   org.statmetrics.Statmetrics

or

> java -classpath "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/*" -jar
>   /home/elias/statmeics/statmetrics.jar org.statmetrics.Statmetrics

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.statmetrics.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.statmetrics.dw.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.statmetrics.dx.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 12 more
```

Sincerely,
Elias Tsolis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. My stupidity.

First step: You must set the corresponding Java: I had Java 11 but I set as Java lib path the 8th version! 
- You can do set the Java version from here:

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

2nd step: Then run the following command, by changing path and file names to your corresponding path and files:

```
  java -classpath "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/*" -jar /home/elias/statmetrics/statmetrics.jar org.statmetrics.Statmetrics
```

It was run succesfully!